# Don't know how to GROUP_BY my data

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a description of my tables

```
describe book;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| isbn           | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title          | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_published | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| publisher_id   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe author;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| author_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe stored_on;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| isbn         | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_copies | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| shelf_number | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| library      | varchar(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe written_by;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| isbn      | varchar(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| author_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am trying to display book name, list of authors that wrote that book, shelf number, total copies, and the library the book is located at.

```
SELECT 
    b.title, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',a.first_name, a.last_name )) AS authors,
    so.shelf_number,
    so.total_copies,
    so.library
FROM 
    stored_on so 
LEFT OUTER JOIN book b ON so.isbn = b.isbn
LEFT OUTER JOIN written_by wb ON wb.isbn = so.isbn
LEFT OUTER JOIN author a ON wb.author_id = a.author_id
GROUP BY (b.title);
```

I don't know how to group my data at the end in a way that will give me duplicate titles/isbn.

Example: There is a book at one library, and the same book at another library, I want to print out the data for each one. They are all listed in my stored_on table to begin with, and I can print out all of the entries when I don't use `GROUP_CONCAT`, but I do get double entries in the `authors` field.

Cannot seem to figure this one out.

Comment: `GROUP BY` everything except `so.total_copies` and include `count(so.total_copies)` in your `SELECT`

Comment: I grouped by `b.title`, `so.shelf_number`, `so.library` and that worked! Thank you!